# Custom message view with animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

The goal is a message appearing in any given view at a given position with an animation duration and a timer for removal from the parent view:
[image]
Creating a NSObject that returns the view, is pretty much what i have so far.
I would like to avoid having to implement a lot of delegate methods in my view controller, for anything other than when the notice has been removed.

Links to resources that could help me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For achieving that I use [WBNoticeView](https://github.com/tciuro/NoticeView). It's easy to use and provides a error view and a success view that can be used on any view. If you want a different appearance you can customize it changing the background and the error or success image.